# Is there any way to show jquery QTip on React js cell?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, reactjs

We have used React JS and angular js to develop a table component. My Requirement is to show qtip on hover of the particular button inside any cell of the table. I have created angular directive with class restriction. However my directive won't be loaded with react cell. 
So, is there any way to do this?

Thanks,
Jay

Comment: Why do you use an angular directive? When the component mounts, attach the Jquery component. The pattern is well documented. https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/use-react-with-other-libraries.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your issue, but you can run your jQuery code on componentDidMount, and you can get a reference to the component's DOM node with findDOMNode.

```
var Component = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function() {
        $(this.findDOMNode()).find('.selector-to-cell').qTip();
    }
});
```